# SQL query giving repetitive results

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables and I want to fetch select columns from the tables.
table 1 is `sfpinventoryinfo` and table 2 is `opticalportinfo`.

Both have `NEID` as common.

```
SELECT 
  sfpinventoryinfo.NEID, 
  sfpinventoryinfo.SlotNumber, 
  sfpinventoryinfo.PortNo, 
  sfpinventoryinfo.PortType,
  sfpinventoryinfo.`Type`, 
  sfpinventoryinfo.SN, 
  sfpinventoryinfo.GenDes,
  sfpinventoryinfo.ApplicationCode,
  opticalportinfo.ChannelFrequency
FROM
   sfpinventoryinfo 
JOIN 
   opticalportinfo ON sfpinventoryinfo.NEID = opticalportinfo.NEID;
```

But I am getting weird results:

[image]

As shows above result, Slot no 4 should have only 1 entry for port instead of 5

Comment: Show some table data.

Comment: Please read this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query  and edit your question

Comment: When you want to help yourself, add a GROUP BY POrtNo to your query and see if that helps you, you propably need to add more columns to the GROUP BY and also learn about aggregation functions.

Comment: You're missing a field in your join clause somewhere. Can you show us a SELECT * from that query? Should be easy to spot..

Comment: Alternatively, you can use SELECT DISTINCT if you can't get rid of the duplicates any other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely your `opticalportinfo` has six rows with the value 13 in `NEID`. So, your join produces all six rows in your result set.

It's hard to guess the "right" way to choose which of those six rows to use without knowing more about your application. You can hack around the problem with SELECT DISTINCT if you must. But it's a hack.

Answer (score 0):

You clearly have duplicates in one or both tables.  In your example data, the entire row looks duplicated, so you could use `select distinct` so entire rows are not repeated:

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.NEID, i.SlotNumber, i.PortNo, i.PortType, i.`Type`, i.SN, 
       i.GenDes, i.ApplicationCode, oi.ChannelFrequency
FROM sfpinventoryinfo i JOIN
     opticalportinfo op
     ON i.NEID = oi.NEID;
```

Or perhaps `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT i.NEID, i.SlotNumber, i.PortNo, i.PortType, i.`Type`, i.SN, 
       i.GenDes, i.ApplicationCode, MAX(oi.ChannelFrequency)
FROM sfpinventoryinfo i JOIN
     opticalportinfo op
     ON i.NEID = oi.NEID
GROUP BY i.NEID, i.SlotNumber, i.PortNo, i.PortType, i.`Type`, i.SN, 
         i.GenDes, i.ApplicationCode;
```

That said, *you* really need to understand why there are duplicates and adjust your query or fix your data.